# What is encryption IV for?

Tags: encryption, xor

What is the IV in encryption used for?

Is this a valid example for encryption with IV? (Pseudocode)

Encryption->xor data with key, prepend IV to output
Decryption->just remove IV and xor the rest with same key

Comment: You probably want to take some time to read [Wikipedia: Initialization Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Your example makes no sense?

Answer (score 3):

The IV (Initialization Vector) is designed to be random for each message so that two identical messages encrypted with the same key are not the same thus leaking information. The IV does not need to be secret so it can just prefix the encrypted message.

The point is that the IV causes the entire encrypted message to be different, adding it to the message is just one common way to make it available for decryption.

Consider the case where Alice sends Bob a message every day of where they will meet, either the mall or the post office. With the same key and IV eavesdropping Eve after noticing where they meet but not knowing which location can tell just be looking at the encrypted message without need to decrypt it. It could be "attack at dawn" or "attack at dusk".

The key can be pre-shared once and reused securely for many messages just by using a [different random](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png) IV for each message.